# Как добавить кнопку на панель в списке элементов инфоблока?

Tags: битрикс

суть задачи - добавить кнопку выгрузки элементов на панель, которая находится в списке элементов инфоблока. Функциональность кнопки я написал, а как разместить ее в панели (рядом с остальными кнопками управления) - непонятно. Я пробовал добавлять кнопку в тексте `result_modifier.php`, но она не отображается (может сделал что не так).

Как лучше поступить в данном случае ?

PS. речь идет о стандартном компоненте, для админки аналогичная задача решена.
вот пример такой панели:

[image: Панель списка элементов инфоблока]

Изначально, для вывода кнопки решил немного изменить шаблон стандартного компонента `components/bitrix/lists.list`
В документации написано, что для изменения данных, передаваемых в массиве параметров, можно использовать `result_modifier.php`. В нем я попытался "на лету" добавить кнопку следующего вида (надеясь, что все это будет обработано `template.php`):

```
$arToolbar[] = array(
    "TEXT" => GetMessage("Выгрузить в Excel с шаблоном"),
    "TITLE" => GetMessage("CT_BLL_EXPORT_EXCEL_TITLE"),
    "LINK" => "/local/modules/sg.xlreport/lib/export_excel.php?id={$id}", //путь к скрипту выгрузки в excel
    "ICON" => "btn",
);
```

Кнопка не появилась на панели, в связи с чем возникли вопросы - а правильно ли это в данном случае - работать со стандартным компонентом? Может я вообще начал не с того и данная задача решается проще?

Comment: можно скрин? не совсем понятно (точнее совсем не понятно) о какой панели вы сейчас говорите.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос. Кнопку необходимо вынести туда же, где располагаются кнопки "Добавить элемент", "Управление разделами" и прочие

Comment: Пожалуйста читайте [как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Во-первых какая редакция 1С-Битрикс, управление сайтом или Битрикс24(облачный\коробочный), какая версия ядра? Какой код вы написали, что не отрабатывает, что вы ожидаете?

Comment: Портал сделан на 1С-Битрикс: Корпоративный портал 15.5.1 (Битрикс24 коробочный). Как точно узнать версию ядра?

Comment: 15.5 - версия ядра. Приведите фрагменты кода, который вы написали, чтобы модифицировать вывод, чтобы было видно с чем нужна помощь. здесь помогают решить проблему, а не решают ее за Вас, [как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Добавил подробности в описание вопроса.

Comment: ну отрисовать, созданную кнопку в `template` по переданным из `result_modifier` параметрами вы должны. `result_modifier` не умеет сам ничего выводить он просто передает, он не занимается отрисовкой кнопки, а вы именно этого от него и ждете. как минимум создайте в файле `template` кнопку в параметры которой передавайте значения из `result_modifier`. или вы надеетесь, что система сама за Вас в нужном Вам месте отрисует элемент который вы хотите имея только параметры которыми его нужно заполнить?

Comment: @Николай Сарры Спасибо. Это я понял. Только есть сомнение - а правильно ли я вообще делаю, помещая это в шаблон?? (насколько я понимаю, могут быть проблемы с обновлениями ?) Возможно ли такие изменения реализовать как модуль?

Comment: проблемы будут если вы внесете изменения в фал `component.php`, если вы внимательно читали. `result_modifier` и `template` относятся к шаблону, если толь вы не модифицируете шаблон `.default` или любой другой системный, тогда да, после обновления вы потеряете изменения. Изменение скопированного шаблона позволяет обновляться без проблем.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, все получилось. Порядок был такой: скопировал стандартный шаблон компонента в каталог ./local,  внес нужные изменения (новую кнопку) в template.php.

Comment: Рад был помочь. Оформлю два последних своих комментарии тогда в ответ.

Comment: Да, конечно, оформляйте ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модифицирование файлов `result_modifier.php` и `template.php` в собственном (скопированном) шаблоне компонента будут работать и после обновления продукта.

В файле `result_modifier.php` вы только подготавливаете то, что будет передано в файл `template.php`. Соответственно вы должны в файле `template.php` отрисовать ту самую кнопку для которой в `result_modifier.php` прописали необходимые параметры.

Сам файл `result_modifier.php` не отвечает за вывод в шаблон - этим занимается файл `template.php`.

Соответственно нужную кнопку Вы должны добавить в нужном месте в файл `template.php`.